# How to solve 502 Bad Gateway error when I enable HTTPS on Node JS server?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elb, http-status-code-502

I'm receiving a `502 Bad Gateway` when trying to enable HTTPS on my Node JS server. I have an AWS EC2 instance on which I'm running the server. The EC2 instance is behind an elastic load balancer (ELB). I have attached an SSL certificate from ACM onto the HTTPS listener for this ELB. This works fine when I'm using an HTTP node server. All communication is encrypted up to the ELB, so I can visit my web pages through my domain name using an HTTPS connection. However, I can't send HTTP post requests from an HTTPS page because of the Same Origin Policy. As a result, I'm thinking I need to enable HTTPS on my node server as well.

I have generated some self-signed certificates and created an https server using those. However, now I'm unable to reach my web pages. I just receive a 502 Bad Gateway error. My health checks on the Target Listener on AWS also fail.

[When I ssh into my server, I can see the server itself is running without any problems.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB0jj.png)

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "However, I can't send HTTP post requests from an HTTPS page because of the Same Origin Policy. As a result, I'm thinking I need to enable HTTPS on my node server as well." That is an incorrect assumption. From the browser's perspective the requests will be HTTPS (because the browser only knows about its connection to the load balancer), and the browser is the only thing that enforces the Same Origin Policy. You would never be sending HTTP Post requests, you would always be sending HTTPS to the load balancer.

Comment: This introduces a different issue. If I create an HTTP server and send HTTPS requests, the browser returns with a `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.

Comment: It sounds like you are sending some of your requests directly to the server, when they should all be going through the load balancer.

Comment: You're right I am! I was sending requests to my server's ip address! I've corrected the the route to my domain name and its working. Thank you so much!!